# Flutter: characters' width is automatically reduced when the text reach TextField's other end

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a TextField that has the following feature:

The text inside such TextField can have its characters' width automatically reduced (but those characters' height is not affected) when the typed text reaches the right side of the TextField (given textAlign is TextAlign.left). If we keep typing, the width will just become smaller and smaller but the whole text will still be visible.

Below is an illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

[image]

How can I do that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [auto_size_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field/example) package, like this:

```
AutoSizeTextField(
   controller: _controller,
   minFontSize: 26,
   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
   fullwidth: false,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've read about this package, but it seems like the AutoSizeTextField will reduce the font size gradually (which means both the text width and height are reduced), while I'm looking for something that only reduces the text width, not its height. Is what I'm thinking right?

Comment: it is impossible, when you want to put a long string in smaller screen you need to reduce its size to fit it in that widht.

Comment: hmm, I think it's possible but it must require customization of classes such as TextPainter or something like that, which is difficult for me to do as now I'm still a newcomer to Flutter. Thank you for the suggested package anyway!